# Put two textviews side by side in a layout

Tags: android, textview

I have two textviews i need to put side by side in a layout  and I have to respect two rules:

- Textview2 needs always to be displayed entirely.
- Textview1 has to be cropped if there is no enough room in the layout.

Examples:

Textview1|textview2

Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeextview1...|textview2

Any ideas?

The only way I found that might work is to create a drawable with the text of textview2 and affect it as coumpoundDrawable to textview1.

Comment: does textview1 need to adjust space to spread the textviews to take up width too? in case both textviews are small to fill the entire width

Comment: Post you XML with output so we can edit...

Comment: If you want to achieve this using constraint layout check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52440662/1197454)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Wrap the two TextViews in a LinearLayout.  Assign a layout weight of 0 to textview2 and a layout weight of 1 to textview2.

See here for more info: [Linear Layout Weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

If you play with the example below you'll see that the LinearLayout first allocates space to textview2 (with weight 0) and then allocates whatever remains to textview1 (with weight 1).  If there is insufficient space to accommodate both TextViews, textview1 will be ellipsized first.  In the example below textview2 will only ever become ellipsized if the LinearLayout is smaller than the size of textview2 itself.  Assign a specific layout width to the FrameLayout and see what happens.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#FF0000FF">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFF0000"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="textview1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="#FF00FF00"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="textview2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem with weights is that there might be extra spaces between textviews. I would like textview1 to take just the space it needs to display its text.

Comment: What is the parent view in which you plan to host the TextViews?

Comment: I have no constraints for this. It can be anything (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ...). Currently I tried with RelativeLayout and LinearLayout

Comment: Sounds like all you need is for the LinearLayout that contains the two TextViews to have its layout height and width set to wrap_content. In this case the LinearLayout will be as small as possible (i.e. no space between textview1 or textview2) and if there is insufficient space in the parent limiting the size of the LinearLayout then textview1 will be ellipsized.  I've updated the example to illustrate this with a parent FrameLayout on which you can tweak the fixed width to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks. Use `android:singleLine="true"` instead of `android:maxLines="1"` in first `TextView`.

Answer (score 7):

why do you need that drawable? option: you can use textview1 with a fixed width and ellipsize the end..:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:padding="2dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textview1"
        android:padding="2dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I also thought about this solution but I wanted to use it as a last resort because I don't like using fixed width for layouts. I always find it hard to determine the right width that will render perfectely on every screen sizes and densities

Comment: @Esteam : you can always use the "100dp" from dimens, specifying it that way would decrease the right width problem to a certain extent.  

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_weight=".50"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_weight=".50"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone else problem ASAP

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="textView2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit:**

Output for short textView1 text:

[image]

Output for long textView1 text:

[image]

Comment: As I wrote to Dean, I would like textView1 to take just the space it needs to display its text, no extra spaces between textView1 and textView2

Comment: @Esteam, I've updated my answer as you described at your comment

Comment: Thank you, but now, there is extra spaces on the left of textview1

Comment: @Esteam you can use a dummy view for your requirement. See my edited answer.

Comment: @Esteam if you don't use that dummy view, with a long textView1 content, textView2 is going to be invisible.

Comment: yes but I don't want the extra spaces on the left of textView1 when its content is short. The solution of Dean solved my problem. Thank you very much for your time.