# Displaying a TextView immediately after another

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am a first time developer for Android, so you can say I've been learning as I was developing. For most of my code that doesn't have to do with the XML layout, I had no problem patching my rookie mistakes. With that said, my rookie mistakes has caught up to me in regards to two `TextViews` when I initially designed them with the GUI interface designer (my major rookie mistake).

My `display_city` tv and `display_today_date` tv seem to have a symbiotic relationship with each other. Removal of either one would crash the app. They seem so dependent on each other that changing each other's positioning is impossible (at least from the myriad of things I have tried such as setting layout margins).

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display_city"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/display_today_date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/get_data"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display_today_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/display_pollen_type"/>
```

My question is - how do I simply position `display_today_date` immediately after my `display_city`? When I first started this Android app, I relied a lot on the GUI builder. That was my first rookie mistake, which resulted in this symbiotic relationship I explained.

Currently this is what my app looks like:

[image]

I have tried changing `display_today_date`'s layout to `android:layout_below="@+id/display_city`. This results in a crash. I checked logcat, but it did not give me relevant information to the reason of the crash within the XML file.

P.S. `get_data` is my `TextEdit` box.

Comment: This may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778632/put-two-textviews-side-by-side-in-a-layout#answer-21779017

Answer (score 0):

You already have the city to show above the date with the line android:layout_above="@+id/display_today_date".  You can't have 2 views in a relative layout each reference the other, or it won't be able to figure out what to do.  If you don't want to put the city above the date, delete that line then add the code to place it where you want.

Comment: Hi Gabe. Thanks for the reply again. Could you clarify what you mean? Which line do I have to remove to prevent two relative layouts to not reference each other? Thank you.

Comment: When I remove `android:layout_above="@+id/display_today_date"`, the app would crash on launch. The logcat I get is telling me I am casting a `TextView` to `EditText` when I am not: http://puu.sh/9b5UC/1cd77285a9.png This error only shows up if I remove that layout line.

Comment: That crash is unrelated.  It means you're miscasting a view in your java code.

Comment: However, why does it only appear if I remove those lines in my XML? The error tells me I am casting `TextView get_area_code` (which is the `EditText`) into `EditText`, when in my code, nowhere have I set `get_area_code` as a `TextView`.

Comment: You actually can get an EditView as a TextView, because EditView derives from TextView.  You can't do it the other way.  My bet is you used the wrong id in your findViewById call

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LinearLayout with the orientation set to horizontal.  That way there is no reference to another view.  So if you delete one the other one won't cause the app to crash.