# Place 2 textview beside each other with 2nd textview always visible

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

**What I want :**

When text is short the 21% `TextView` should be just beside the first `TextView` like below

[image]

and when text is long I want the first `TextView` to reach to end and ellipsize and 21% `TextView` should be visible like below

[image]

but what ever I do the 21% `TextView` goes away and first `TextView` occupies complete space . I tried many combinations with `Linear, Relative, Frame, Constraint layout, weight, minwidth` etc but nothing seems to work.

Here is my xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_job_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar nec justo id bibendum." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_matchPercent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="21% "
        android:textColor="#4268e3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea how to achieve it?

**Note:** I do not want to hard code characters or width

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> 1 way Try this Using **`ConstraintLayout`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/longTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text=" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel consectetur tortor. Fusce velit velit, tincidunt vitae dolor at, pharetra condimentum nunc. Etiam ac erat ac nulla tempus ullamcorper id ac sapien."
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/shortTextView"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shortTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="21%"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/longTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/longTextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

## OUTPUT using ConstraintLayout

When Long Text

[image]

When Small Text

[image]

> 2 way  using **`FlexboxLayout`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_alignSelf="flex_start"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel consectetur tortor. Fusce velit velit, tincidunt vitae dolor at, pharetra condimentum nunc. Etiam ac erat ac nulla tempus ullamcorper id ac sapien."
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:text="21%"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="60dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_alignSelf="flex_start"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

## OUTPUT Using **`FlexboxLayout`**

When Long Text

[image]

When Small Text

[image]

Comment: let me try this

Comment: Constraint one is working fine thanks . +1 and accept ,

Comment: Correct solution.

Comment: perfect solution +1

Comment: Applied this above solution in my code but did not work Please check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454453/android-layout-issue-with-relative-layout-and-right-of-property

Comment: @Nicky what issue you are facing?

Comment: Check this screenshot, I've tried your solution but image still compassing when text long

https://screencast.com/t/0LUJ2jpQ

Comment: Now I think I have to. i'm looking for quick solution instead of it took long time mota bhai!!

Comment: For deprecated `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"`, please refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565195/layout-constraintwidth-default-wrap-is-deprecated-any-alternative

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `LinearLayout`, of course it not better than using `ContrainstLayout` or another way. However, hope it help in some situation

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingEnd="50dp"
        android:text="Title 1111111111111111111111111111111"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="-50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="21%"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Testing

input
`Title 1111111111111111111111111111111`
ouput
[image]

input
`Title 1111111`
ouput
[image]

Comment: did you check this when text is long ? I remember trying something similar and did not work

Comment: @Redman yes, I have checked. I have update the image in my answer

Comment: Ok I got it , but this is partially hard coding, If second text is larger than 50dp then this will not work properly

Comment: @Redman you are right. It is not good solution for extendable. `ConstraintLayout` is better. I write this answer because this is my way for solving this problem before `ConstraintLayout` appear. And I think the idea for solve this problem by using LinearLayout may help another people solve another problems