# how to set measurement of an image before its sibling textView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, textview

I have a linear layout with textView and ImageView.

When i enlarge the text size to large, the image view doesn't have enough space so it's partially hidden.

[image]

I want the Image view to be fully displayed and even if the text has to be truncated.

Do i have any simple way to do it? instead of inheriting from LinearLayout and overriding `onMeasure`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440400/place-2-textview-beside-each-other-with-2nd-textview-always-visible/52440662#52440662

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Relative View instead of Linear View.. Relative give more command over this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/first"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="textview"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use layout_weight in Linear Layout.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by:

Linear layout. The imageView with a hard coded DP width and height, Text with 0 width and a weight of 1.