# minHeight is not working with Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have used ImageView and Textview inside RelativeLayout.

What I Expect:

1. Textview height should be wrap_content
2. Imageview should fill the remaining space
3. Minimum height of Imageview is 250dp.

Xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:minHeight="250dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/facebookshare">

    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output : (Imageview height becomes 0)

[image]

Expected : (Imageview height should be >250 dp //minHeight=250dp)

[image]

When Content is small, Imageview should fill the screen like

[image]

Can anyone help me!!!

Comment: Related [Place 2 textview beside each other with 2nd textview always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440400/place-2-textview-beside-each-other-with-2nd-textview-always-visible/52440662#52440662)

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks let me try it for vertical views.

Comment: if possible share your expected output as a image

Comment: @NileshRathod I can explain it. The textview should be visible in the screen even if there is large content. The imageview should fill the remaining space in the screen. But the minimum height of imageview should be 250dp.

Comment: You want scrollable textView with large text?

Comment: @Khemraj No, I should fit to the screen.

Comment: @JyotiJK kindly share the experted output as image for both case to understand your requirements

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: @NileshRathod check the edited question

Comment: @JyotiJK Try my answer now.

Comment: @JyotiJK look at my answer

Comment: @PankajKumar It was my mistake that I did not try any of your and also mine solutions at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:minHeight="250dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tvText"
        android:src="@drawable/kid" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/large_text" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

> When Large text

[image]

> When Small text

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
<string name="large_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar nec justo id bibendum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar nec justo id bibendum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar nec justo id bibendum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar nec justo id bibendum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar nec justo id bibendum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis bibendum mattis risus eget pulvinar. Praesent commodo erat enim, id congue sem tristique vitae. Proin vitae accumsan justo, ut imperdiet tellus. Mauris neque nibh, hendrerit id tortor vel, congue sagittis odio. Morbi elementum lobortis maximus. Etiam sit amet porttitor massa. Fusce sed magna quis arcu tincidunt finibus vitae id erat. Pellentesque massa mi, imperdiet eget accums</string>    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->

    <string name="small_text">Hello World Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    Hello World Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    Hello World Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</string>
```

Comment: But this is the same code which i posted in question. I don't know why it is not working for me :(

Comment: @JyotiJK strange the above code is working fine for me in both case from XML as well as runtime

Comment: @NileshRathod Your answer must work. My first approach was same, but I didn't get why that was not working, even copy paste of your version is also not working for me too.. this comment is not for any negative points in your answer. Actually I wanted to find the cause why this is not working, although it must work.

Comment: @PankajKumar i can understand that no worry about that we all here to help each other

Comment: @NileshRathod Can you please try this code with very long text?

Comment: @PankajKumar let me try

Comment: @NileshRathod & PankajKumar Thank you so much for your effort. Even I checked the questions "Imageview minHeight is not working" . The solution in those questions are to set adjustViewBounds true. But it is not working for me :(

Comment: @NileshRathod No no.Please set the text which can go beyond one screen. Actual problem is there. Even current value of your large-text is not enough to make imageview small or make outside of screen. :(

Comment: @JyotiJK We gave you 2 solutions with ConstraintLayout, did you check that? Both answers have few updates and both are working fine for too large texts also. Even this solution must work but we are trying to find why this is not working

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code if you are using `ConstraintLayout` if not please tell me about it. Need to use `NestedScrollView`:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txt" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @Khemraj i was tested my solution. It work fine with large text. If you need to scroll only text or you need to trim large text I think you can do it yourself

Comment: @Khemraj only if scrolling content is not required

Comment: As PO do not require it. said in a comment `No, I should fit to the screen`.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a hack.

Instead of giving `minHeight` to `ImageView`, you can give `maxLines` to `TextView`. You can also ellipsize `TextView` at the ends that will look good too.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_cat">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        tools:text="asdlfkasdfkasdf"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: img]

Comment: if the text size and linespace is changed, then using max lines concept will be not good idea.

Comment: I did not get you, however you can set maxline according to your need. You can also program for responsive textsize by SSP library.

Answer (score 0):

`minHeight` of `ImageView` not working just because, you have set height of `ImageView` as `match_parent`. Thus, it is getting enough space (more than 250dp to render and ignoring `minHeight`).

Just change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
      android:minHeight="250dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/facebookshare">
```

---

Working sample layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sdvdsibvdsv"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/facebookshare"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linear"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It may, Layout design view will show you incorrect UI rendering. Just run it. It will work.

Comment: I set wrap_content but it sets height less than 250 dp if the textview content is large.

Comment: @JyotiJK Use optimised layout code. It is working what you expected.

Comment: @Khemraj Did you read my answer carefully. What I have written there? Did you try it while running?

Comment: @PankajKumar Okay so that's the issue. I did not test mine solutions also at runtime.

Comment: @PankajKumar Cool, I don't know if it worked your side. this is output in my device. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OE4D.png

Comment: Check this screenshot, I only increased textsize to check. https://i.stack.imgur.com/T22R5.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182859/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-khemraj).

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the ImageView inside another layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear">

        <ImageView
            android:minHeight="250dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/what"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "Enclose the ImageView inside another layout:" why? What makes is to be different from other views?

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it works perfectly. Use layout_weight. set maxWeight for the image and the remaining weight for the text. When the text length is increased it will reduce image height. It depends on the length of the text you provide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Hhhjkahsgkjhasd jasdhfkjsd hfdjkshfuernf jsdhfsudf jdhfkjdshf jhdfjshf kjdhf kjdhf kajhdf  jhsgdfs jd sdgfjkgf sjdgfs jfshdg "/>
</LinearLayout>
```