# Two horizontal TextViews with dynamic width of first TextView using XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to built layout where is 2 TextViews.

First TextView has undefined length (?). So it must be singleline and ellipsize end.

Second TextView has defined width (wrap_content).

I need second textview to append to end of first textview, but if first textview has too much content length it should be ellipsized.

Also, second textview must stay at the end of parent container.

I know it's a bit confusing. Just look at pictures below.

[image]

[image]

Can it be done without java/kotlin coding, just simple xml?

Comment: Thanks for editing!

Comment: you can use constraintlayout.

Comment: @RahulKumar Can you show an example, please? I've tried to make it using ConstraintLayout, but it has no success :( It will be really nice if I can make it with ConstraintLayout

Comment: Why not just `LinearLayout` with `orientation:horizontal` :)

Comment: @makvasic because it has wrong behaviour. With LinearLayout "short" textview will always be at right side. And I need to "short" textview align to end of "long" textview, but if "long" textview is too long, it must be ellipsized and "short" textview must align to right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="0">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                tools:text="abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                tools:text="(1001)" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: You are my savior! :)

Comment: TableLayout is _really_ old and honestly should not be used anymore now that we have RelativeLayout or even better - ConstraintLayout (which is more recent and gets updated).

Comment: @ZUNJAE I agreed, but can you please give me working example using ConstraintLayout? It should works like this solution

Comment: @ZUNJAE yes you are right here is the solution using `ConstraintLayout` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440400/place-2-textview-beside-each-other-with-2nd-textview-always-visible/52440662#52440662

Comment: @LIFED check out this   here is the solution using `ConstraintLayout`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440400/place-2-textview-beside-each-other-with-2nd-textview-always-visible/52440662#52440662

Comment: @NileshRathod oh thank you so much! app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" it is that I missed. This is the best solution!

Comment: @LIFED welcome happy to help u

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="Long" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Short" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does not match the question :(

Comment: I understand now the problem with `LinearLayout`... Learned something new today. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go with constraint layout implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Abc"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.031"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="llksdnflskdnflsdnfkjsllksdnflskdnflsdnfkjskjdfnkl 
    jsnkljndkljd" />
```

Comment: Sorry, this method is not working. It's just like LinearLayout with "long" textview weight = 1. Please see my explanation comment at my root post