# Wrong TextView position in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two TextView in LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Very long long long long long text"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this: [image]

If I remove `android:gravity="center"` it looks fine. But I need to use it. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wrong TextView position in LinearLayout

You need to set **`android:gravity="center"`** in your `LinearLayout`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedback_binary_left_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedback_binary_right_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:text="Very long long long long long text"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Also check this  if you want to shaw all the text

- [Place 2 textview beside each other with 2nd textview always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52440400/7666442)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Very long long long long long text"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I added `android:gravity="center"` to parent `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `weight_sum` in your `LinearLayout` and then use a `match_parent` width and height , than giving both `EditText` a `weight=50` value or more or less , depends on the text you want .

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/very_long_text"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **`fill_parent`** is deprecated