# How to make a TextView in a LinearLayout fill the remaining space and being truncable

Tags: android, textview, width, android-linearlayout, truncate

I've a `ListView` containing some rows, and especially a row combining **categories** and **distance** items in 2 `TextView`:

- the **category** item can contain one or more categories, so this `TextView` must be **truncable**
- the **distance** item is only displayed if the user has allowed the geolocation, so this `TextView` can be **hidden**
- in this case, the *category* item must fill all the **row's width**

The expected result looks like this screenshot from the Maps app on iOS:
[image: Maps screenshot]

I've tried to doing this with a LinearLayout, but this doesn't work as expected:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/AffiliateCellDetail"
              android:layout_below="@id/AffiliateCellTitle"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/AffiliateCellCategories"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:ellipsize="end"
              android:singleLine="true"/>        
    <TextView android:id="@+id/AffiliateCellDistance"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>         
</LinearLayout>
```

***Is there a better approach to achieve this?***

Comment: Have you tried `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52440662/7666442

Comment: Thanks guys, this worked with ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally achieve this by using `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/AffiliateCellDetail"
        android:layout_below="@id/AffiliateCellTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/AffiliateCellCategories"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:ellipsize="end"
              android:singleLine="true"
              app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
              app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
              app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/AffiliateCellDistance"/>        
    <TextView android:id="@+id/AffiliateCellDistance"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/AffiliateCellCategories"
              app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/AffiliateCellCategories"
              app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>                
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/AffiliateCellDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AffiliateCellCategories"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AffiliateCellDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`android:layout_weight="1"` will make the category TextView expand whenever there is place to fill.

Comment: Thanks @hiddeneyes02 but this doesn't work, the AffiliateCellDistance is always fixed to the right, which is not the expected behavior.
I've managed to achieve this with ConstraintLayout, like suggested by Batch Vu or Nilesh.