# Horizontal layout in which one element is a fixed width and the other as wide as possible

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been fighting Android for a very simple task and can't for the life of me figure it out. I've tried `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` and gave `ContraintLayout` a go, to no avail.

Simplified, what I want a horizontal layout with two elements:

```
+-----------------------+-------+
|         Hello         | World |
+-----------------------+-------+
```

Each element will itself be a layout. For the purpose of this example, each of those layouts will contain a `TextView`. The element containing the `TextView` "World" should be 100dp wide. The element containing the `TextView` "Hello" should match the parent's width but not overlap with "World". Basically "as wide as possible while respecting the other elements".

My current attempt is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="32sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings_bar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="World"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, this is what I get: the first layout completely covers the second one.
[image: UI example]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52440662/7666442

Comment: you say "Each element will itself be a layout" - why does each element need to be a layout? constraintlayout can usually flatten out layout hierarchies like this

Comment: you can use weight and weightSum properties of layouts to achieve your objective.

Comment: @kkarakk The current state of the application has them being layouts. I am hoping I can get away with a minor refactoring to achieve this instead of changing the whole layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kept your layouts. Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp" 
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="32sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings_bar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="World"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I removed

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_frame"
```

from `settings_bar`.
I added

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

to `main_frame`

Comment: This worked, thanks! I just had to add `android:layout_marginRight="100dp"` to `main_frame` so that `settings_bar` was not on top of it but next to it.

Comment: `100dp` is rather long margin. Consider testing it in various devices.

Comment: Although this is intended to run in a single, well-known device, I am curious: is there another way apart from the margin to keep both layouts from stepping on each other?

Comment: With other types of layout, like a ConstraintLayout you set constraints. With LinearLayout the views are positioned by design one next to each other. But the margin works for every type of layout if you set it correctly and in your case it's the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `layout_weight` property of `textview` to achieve this kind of functionality

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/settings_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_frame"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

       <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="32sp" />
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="32sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As I said, I need the second element to have a fixed size of 100dp.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really simple layout and can be easily achieved with `constraintLayout`. I am not including the `FrameLayout` and `LinearLayout` you have used as wrappers. You can add them as wrappers with the same width and height as the `TextView` and it won't affect the layout. Here you go -

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/world"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/world"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="World"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When you set `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` for the 2nd layout ("World"), it aligns the layout to the end (right). I have set its custom width with `android:layout_width="100dp"`.

For the 1st layout ("Hello"), you will use

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/world"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

with `android:layout_width="0dp"`. 0dp won't actually set the width to 0 but will make it stretch between its constraints. So in this case, it will set its start (left) to the parent's start and it will set its end to the start (left) of the 2nd layout. So, it will simply stretch till that layout.

Here is how it looks like -

[image: Sample layout of above xml with blueprint]