# Constraint layout for chat activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I am attempting to design a chat item in a RecyclerView with constraint layout but a can't set the flexible width correctly.

Android constraint layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/receive_message_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/receive_message_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@color/receive_message_box_text"
            android:background="@drawable/message_recieve"
            android:padding="@dimen/message_box_padding"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/receive_time_label"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    />


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/receive_time_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="timestamp"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"

            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_between_message_element"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/receive_message_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It works well but if I show some longer message, the timestamp is hidden by receive message label.

[image: device behaviour]
[image: layout in designer]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52440662/7666442

Comment: it works much better (message is flexible + time is visible), but how can I move time to right, please?

Comment: I removed constraint_start from timestamp. It works, but I hope it's correct solution

Comment: And for mirrored (sent from phone) I used in top constraint layout wrapper right-to-left direction and works well. I hope, that can be useful for somebody.  

`android:layoutDirection="rtl"`

Answer (score 1):

**UPD.** My previous solution was incorrect as @aimin-pan mentioned.

you should set for you message textView
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`, and right constraint before left side of time textView.
And time textView just align on top-right of parent.

[image]

In this case if you have short text it will be wrap context:
[image]

And if the text is long it will also correct wrap:
[image]

Full xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="#F00"
        android:text="asdf asdf aasdf"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I've been searching for this my whole life! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The solution from anber is good, but the chat content textView will have extended width, even when the content is very short, which may become not good.

I also did something very similar. Finally I used a solution as:

- use a LinearLayout (or any other layout) which has width=0 (match_constraint) to replace the TextView
- move TextView as child of above layout, and set its width=wrap_content

Thus the time will show anyway, and the chat content width is still wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

In your time `TextView` remove this line

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/receive_message_label"
```

So, the time label is not constrained to the message, but only the message to the time.

Set also the message label width to 0dp

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a Blank View After Time textView

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout3" />
```