# Put 2 views side by side with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to put 2 textViews side by side in ConstraintLayout while the left view has a dynamic text (can be either short text or a very long text that should be ellipsis if it's overlapping the second view).
I want that the 2 textviews will be side by side, so the second view will start at the end of the first view.

Please help :-)

Comment: Do you mean you want them to occupy 50% of the space each? You haven't explained what width you want the second TextView to be

Comment: Please include the XML of your previous attempts, and a description (or image) of how you want the final layout to look.

Comment: I think this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440400/place-2-textview-beside-each-other-with-2nd-textview-always-visible

Comment: @ManoharReddy That's exactly what I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone, found the answer with the help of @ManoharReddy
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440400/place-2-textview-beside-each-other-with-2nd-textview-always-visible

Answer (score 4):

Though this is the simplest one , if you want them to occupy the same space then you can use layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Random 1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Random 1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text_view1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Have a look to this https://medium.com/@loutry/guide-to-constraintlayout-407cd87bc013 .ChainStyle is generally used when you want them to spread equally either horizontal or vertical .Chains are controlled by attributes set on the first element of the chain (the “head” of the chain) which is the left-most widget for horizontal chains, and the top-most widget for vertical chains.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... Just adjust to top and bottom of the views according to your layout.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leftView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:text="Left View"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rightView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:text="Right View"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/leftView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/txt1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```