# layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" is deprecated any alternative?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I was using this layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" in textview to keep the textview content wrapped(to right of it there is imageview),  as the text in textview increases textview area will grow which moves the imageview to right.

```
layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
```

As it is deprecated any alternatives?

**Logcat**

[image]

Comment: `layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` deprecated. sure?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes getting this error message in logcat

Comment: Include logcat with question

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Added

Comment: ok. Then use what they suggest on logcat

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Following are the changes i have made for solution, imageview will not go outside the visible screen area :

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadsasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I was searching for the better part of day and couldn't find this solution posted anywhere else.

Comment: <3 This works and I don't understand why after tweaking the various constraints for the last hour!!

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

width cannot be “0dp”

Answer (score 4):

As the documentation says in this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#wrap_content-:-enforcing-constraints--added-in-1.1-) from **Android Developers**:

> In versions before 1.1 they will be treated as a literal dimension -- meaning, constraints will not limit the resulting dimension. While in general, this is enough (and faster), in some situations, you might want to use WRAP_CONTENT, yet keep enforcing constraints to limit the resulting dimension. In that case, you can add one of the corresponding attributes:

`app:layout_constrainedWidth="true|false"`

Hence, use `layout_constrainedWidth="true"` instead of `layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"`.

Answer (score 4):

If a dimension is set to **`WRAP_CONTENT`**, in versions **before 1.1** they will be treated as a literal dimension-meaning, constraints will not limit the resulting dimension.

> It’s often required that view width or height to remain as wrap
>   content instead of match constraint or match parent but unfortunately
>   wrap content override the constraint applied and overlap with the
>   constraint if width or height changes. With version 1.1.0 this issue
>   is resolved by using

```
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"  OR  app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

**FYI**

You can use **`percentage`** for width and height the dimension should be **`match constraint(0dp)`** and **`app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"`** or **`app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"`** need to set as percent.

**Example**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello Width In Percentage"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
```

**GRADLE**

```
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3' // For androidx
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```