# Android layout how to horizontal align textView with dynamical width

Tags: android, android-layout

Having 4 views A (TextView), B(icon), C(TextView), D (TextView) horizontally aligned next to each other.

B and D have fixed width. The text will be filled in the onBindView().

Their parent's width could be calculated based on the screen orientation.

It requires to show A as much as possible, and the C will consume the rest or up to its content width (if not enough space then show ellipsis).

And all A, B, C, D should left align the right edge of the previous one.

There are a few cases but these four cover most of them.

```
1. Parent width is enough for all

|-|AAAA|B|CCCCCCCC|DDD|--------------|-|

2. C is too large and have to show ellipses


|-|AAAAA|B|CCCCCCCCCCCCC...|DDD|-|

  3. A is large and have to show ellipse for C to be able to show

|-|AAAAAAA..........|B|CCCCCCCC|DDD|-|



4. the parent width is not enough for showing A and C completely, so A and C both show ellipses


|-|AAAAAAAAAAAAAA...|B|CCCCC...|DDD|-|
```

so the rule is to show A as much as possible, C shows either in full or with ellipses,  in case with showing C's minWidth and still cannot show the A in full then show A with ellipsis.

Tried LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout and cant get the desired result.

this has two maxWidth for A and C, the problem is if either A or C is too small the other one may still show ellipsis without using all available space.

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/a_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxWidth="130dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="ee" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b_checked"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/checked" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/c_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxWidth="150dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="aasdasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/d_time"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            tools:text="30 Nov 18"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

If do it in a derived view and override the onMeasure(), the calculation is not straight forward and the A, C width may not immediately available.

How to do it just in layout xml, or is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this meets your requirements, but this is my attempt using `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eee"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="something very very very very very long"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/two"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fixed"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/one"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/one"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/three"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eee"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="this is pretty short"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/one"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/two"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/four"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fixed"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/one"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/three"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The important parts here are that the first "stretchable" view uses `wrap_content` while the second uses `0dp` plus `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"`. This will give the space to the first view at a higher priority than the second view, but will allow both to grow and shrink.

The only problem I've found is that, when the first view's text is **very** long, it can push the other views on top of each other. This could potentially be solved by adding a maximum width to the first view:

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_max="256dp"
```

Some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it seems working (need the maxWidth which is hard to choose for both portrait and landscape). Other post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56580441/2987953) mentioned  `layout_constraintWidth_default` is deprecated and using `layout_constrainedWidth=”true"` does the same.

Comment: `layout_constrainedWidth=”true"` behavior not same as `layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"`, layout_constrainedWidth=true has the 4th view push away and not flow by right side of the 3rd view. so have to use `layout_constraintWidth_default` as Ben did.