# Cannot spread children views to the sides of their parent linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, gravity

I want to create a layout with 2 views inside.

1) A `GroupView` with a`textView` to the left

2) A `imageView` to the right

There is a minimal gap between them so if the textView is too long, it truncates its content, but the image is never shrinked.

Here is my try:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <myTextView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/my_text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" />


  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/my_image"
      android:layout_width="18dp"
      android:layout_height="18dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my_margin_vertical"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/my_margin_vertical"
      android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/my_margin_end"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/my_margin_end"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_color_18_vd" />
</LinearLayout>
```

but the outcome doesn't push the children views to the side, nor keeps the gap between them in favor to the image.

How can i fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440400/place-2-textview-beside-each-other-with-2nd-textview-always-visible/52440662#52440662

Comment: You could try the Constraint layout : https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: @PoyyamozhiRamakrishnan yes. but wanted to keep it simple. with linear layout

Comment: so then you'd have to use layout_weights to avoid overlapping, or you can use relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by setting weight to your textview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <myTextView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/my_text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" />


  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/my_image"
      android:layout_width="18dp"
      android:layout_height="18dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my_margin_vertical"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/my_margin_vertical"
      android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/my_margin_end"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/my_margin_end"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_color_18_vd" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this will solve image#1, but what about image #2? i want the text to be truncated